# Sorting contents of a file based on start_time

Tags: java, date, arraylist

I have a particular text file containing data for each of the respective fields ie Application ID,User,Type,Queue and start_time. I would want the output to be sorted on start_time and display all those application_ids which are running for more than 24 hours.

A sample eg is below:

```
ApplicationID   User    Type       Queue    start_time
appln_id_1     abcdef   MAPREDUCE   abc     Wed Jan20 2015:59:06+0550 2016
appln_id_2     deghif   TEZ         def     Tue Jan19 2015:08:16+0550 2016
appln_id_3     deghdf   TEZ         def     Sun Jan17 2015:04:02+0550 2016
appln_id_4     dghkif   MAPREDUCE   ghi     Mon Jan18 2015:15:26+0550 2016.
```

I want the result to be sorted on start_times.

After sorting , the result should be as below:

```
ApplicationID   User    Type       Queue    start_time
appln_id_3     deghdf   TEZ         def     Sun Jan17 2015:04:02+0550 2016
appln_id_4     dghkif   MAPREDUCE   ghi     Mon Jan18 2015:15:26+0550 2016
appln_id_2     deghif   TEZ         def     Tue Jan19 2015:08:16+0550 2016
appln_id_1     abcdef   MAPREDUCE   abc     Wed Jan20 2015:59:06+0550 2016.
```

I am able to sort the start_times and put it into a list.But how to display the output as above, as the output of each of the column changes after sorting.

I would want the output to be sorted on start_time and display all those application_ids which are running for more than 24 hours.
Here is my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
Date date = sdf.parse(start_time);
String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date);
System.out.println("date is"+formattedDate);
list1.add(formattedDate);
System.out.println("list is"+list1);
Collections.sort(list1);
System.out.println("sorted list"+list1);
```

Any Help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: I am confused by the offset-from-UTC of `+0550` in your example data. I do not find [any particular time zone listed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) with an offset of `+05:50`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class representing the record in the file. Parse the record and create list of records. Write your own comparator for custom sort logic.Sort list by passing a custom comparator to Collections.sort(list, comparator).